# How do I make sharp parts?

Tags: modeling

I want to make a scythe like this one but I can’t because I don’t know how to do the sharp parts

[image: scythe example for the sharp parts]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are smoothing your object, you lose often the sharpen look, but you can work around this, one option is to give your object more information to work with by addding more edges/verts. For example if you're using a subdivision modifier:

a subdi on a cubes looks like this:
[image]

adding more geometry to the edges will sharpen the edges:
[image]

if you do this with every edge it can look like this:
[image]

A second optiom is to mark edges sharp but you also can combine both. You can mark them sharp by selecting an edge, right click, and select mark sharp.